# How to sort these datetime object elements array in the following code?

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

I am trying to make reminder application using python but when I try to sort out time for various task I can sort but I need to change the form and I cannot get back to the original form
Here in sort function I made the tr_arr Numpy array element of 12 hour format to datetime format by parsing the string using strptime method but when I sorted it and wanted my time original into 12 hour format it is showing error.
Following is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime as dtm
import numpy as np


def sort_rem(tr_arr,r_arr):
    a=tr_arr
    print(a)
    
    for i in range(len(tr_arr)):
        tr_arr[i]=dtm.strptime(tr_arr[i],"%I:%M:%S %p")
       
    print(tr_arr)
    
    for i in range(len(tr_arr)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(tr_arr)):
            if tr_arr[i]>tr_arr[j]:
                temp=tr_arr[i]
                tr_arr[i]=tr_arr[j]
                tr_arr[j]=temp
                temp=r_arr[i]
                r_arr[i]=r_arr[j]
                r_arr[j]=temp
    print(tr_arr)
    print(r_arr)

    for i in range(len(tr_arr)):
        for j in range(len(tr_arr)):
            if tr_arr[i]==dtm.strptime(a[j],"%I:%M:%S %p"):
                tr_arr[i]=a[j]
                
    print(tr_arr)
    return tr_arr , r_arr


class Alarm():
    def set_alm():
        aH=input("Enter the hour to remind you at:")
        aM=input("Enter the minute to remind you at:")
        aS=input("Enter the second to remind you at:")
        amp=input("Enter AM/PM:")

        if int(aH)<=12 and int(aM)<=59 and int(aS)<=59 and (amp=='AM' or amp=='PM'):
            if len(aH)==1:
                aH='0'+aH
            else:
                pass
            if len(aM)==1:
                aM='0'+aM
            else:
                pass
            if len(aS)==1:
                aS='0'+aS
            else:
                pass
            t_str=f"{aH}:{aM}:{aS} {amp}"
            return t_str

        else:
            print("Please enter values of hour,minute and seconds and AM/PM in correct range!!")
    
n_task=int(input("Enter the number of tasks for the reminder:"))

rem_arr=np.array([])
trem_arr=np.array([])
for i in range(n_task):
    rem=input("Enter the task you want to do:")
    rem_arr=np.append(rem_arr,rem)
    trem=Alarm.set_alm()
    trem_arr=np.append(trem_arr,trem)


print(trem_arr,rem_arr)
sort_rem(trem_arr,rem_arr)
print(trem_arr,rem_arr)
```

Error:

```
Enter the number of tasks for the reminder:2
Enter the task you want to do:Eat
Enter the hour to remind you at:3
Enter the minute to remind you at:2
Enter the second to remind you at:20
Enter AM/PM:PM
Enter the task you want to do:Sleep
Enter the hour to remind you at:4
Enter the minute to remind you at:50
Enter the second to remind you at:55
Enter AM/PM:AM
['03:02:20 PM' '04:50:55 AM'] ['Eat' 'Sleep']
['03:02:20 PM' '04:50:55 AM']
['1900-01-01 15:02:20' '1900-01-01 04:50:55']
['1900-01-01 04:50:55' '1900-01-01 15:02:20']
['Sleep' 'Eat']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Python\ALM.py", line 73, in <module>
    sort_rem(trem_arr,rem_arr)
  File "e:\Python\ALM.py", line 28, in sort_rem
    if tr_arr[i]==dtm.strptime(a[j],"%I:%M:%S %p"):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '1900-01-01 04:50:55' does not match format '%I:%M:%S %p'
PS E:\Python>
```

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: Use a single array storing a tuple of (datetime.time,str) and use the built-in `sort`.  Convert the time  *before* putting it in the array as `datetime.time` is sortable.  When you print the array, *then* format as you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First look at the output, your input was only "h/m/s" but you receive date with format "y-m-d i:m:s" so the problem is with changing the format. You can see it also in ValueError.

To change format of the date in specified format you can provide format as below:

```
for i in range(len(tr_arr)):
   tr_arr[i]=dtm.strptime(tr_arr[i],"%I:%M:%S %p").strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
```

To sort list of date time object you can use list method sort():

```
tr_arr.sort()
print("sorted:",tr_arr)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution you gave right solution that we need to change format but as out string contains year month and day additionally so we cannot parse it so there is a small change we need do as                                                                         tr_arr[i]=dtm.strptime(tr_arr[i],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")    now it will execute correctly without error and I cannot use sort function as it could sort with number but not with AM/PM and also I need to sort for remainder along with time so I cannot use sort function.

Comment: You can sort datetime objects that use 12-hour time format with objects that use 24-hour time format. So you are missing something.  You can make nested list and then use "key=" argument in sort function to sort by time.